# Android Kitkat and open intent

Tags: android, html, android-4.4-kitkat

i need to open local html file in external web browser.

I trying something like this:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(htmlFile);
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    i.setType("text/html");
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Chose browser"));
```

Before Kitkat i was able to open that file with:

```
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(htmlFile);
    i.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
    i.setData(uri);
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> I trying something like this:

Try `text/html` as the MIME type. Also, since you are using a file, that file needs to be available on external storage. Or, consider using `FileProvider` to serve it, if you would prefer to keep it on internal storage.

Also, bear in mind that the current user may not have access to a Web browser (e.g., restricted profile on an Android 4.3+ tablet).

> Before Kitkat i was able to open that file with:

Allow the user to choose the Web browser, please, rather than hard-coding it to some value.

Besides, that browser does not exist on all Android devices.

Comment: File is available, i creating this file just before open.

Answer (score 0):

OK so there is no default activity which can handle file URI. 
The best solution of that problem is to write own activty with WebView component.